# Image gallery button does not fade out and the image dissapears

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

In the below gallery everything works good except when clicking the previous button. The first image disappears and the button does not fade out!

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ub56gs8y/2/

```js
  function checkIimg() {
    if ($(".sample:first").hasClass("img-active")) {
      $(".b1").fadeOut(100);
    } else {
      $(".b1").fadeIn(100);
    }

    if ($(".sample:last").hasClass("img-active")) {
      $(".b2").fadeOut(100);
    } else {
      $(".b2").fadeIn(100);
    }
  }

  checkIimg();

  $(".buttons button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("b2")) {
      $(".sample.img-active").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").next(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
        checkIimg();
      });
    } else {
      $(".sample.img-active").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").prev(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
        checkIimg();
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
.img-hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 gallery-images">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="sample img-active" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/people" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/tech" class="sample img-hidden" />
       </div>

       <div class="buttons">
         <button class="b1">previous</button>
         <button class="b2">Next</button>

       </div>
     </div>
```

```
  $(".buttons button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("b2")) {
      $(".sample.img-active").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").next(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
    checkIimg();
      });
    } else {
      $(".sample.img-active").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").prev(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
        checkIimg();
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `img-hidden` class to the hidden images.

Add it after selecting the element, before fading:

`$(".sample.img-active").addClass("img-hidden").fadeOut(...`

Full example:

```js
function checkIimg() {
    if ($(".sample:first").hasClass("img-active")) {
      $(".b1").fadeOut(100);
    } else {
      $(".b1").fadeIn(100);
    }

    if ($(".sample:last").hasClass("img-active")) {
      $(".b2").fadeOut(100);
    } else {
      $(".b2").fadeIn(100);
    }
  }

  checkIimg();

  $(".buttons button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("b2")) {
      $(".sample.img-active").addClass("img-hidden").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").next(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
        checkIimg();
      });
    } else {
      $(".sample.img-active").addClass("img-hidden").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("img-active").prev(".img-hidden").addClass("img-active").fadeIn(100);
        checkIimg();
      });
    }
  });
```

```css
.img-hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-12 gallery-images">
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/any" class="sample img-active" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/arch" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/people" class="sample img-hidden" />
         <img src="https://placeimg.com/100/100/tech" class="sample img-hidden" />
       </div>

       <div class="buttons">
         <button class="b1">previous</button>
         <button class="b2">Next</button>

       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.